# Move from comment to cell and remove

Tags: excel, vba, replace, automation, comments

I want move from comment to cell and remove  "Alvise Tran:" by VBA
The displayed result will be like cell H3, H7, H11

[image]
Thanks

Comment: What code did you try, and what's the specific problem you had when trying to get it to run?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will work: add code to module, select cells to change, run code.

```
Sub Move_To_Comment_And_Clear_Comment()

Dim CL As Range
Dim RG As Range
Dim Commenttext As String
Set RG = Selection

    If RG.Cells.Count > 200 Then
        If MsgBox("You have selected more than the recommended range size of 200 cells." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Total Cells Selected = " & RG.Cells.Count & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Are you SURE you want to run this? It could take a considerable amount of time or freeze your workbook.", _
            vbYesNo, "WARNING") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For Each CL In RG.Cells
        If Not CL.Comment Is Nothing Then
            Commenttext = CL.Comment.Text
            With CL
                CL.Value = Mid(Commenttext, InStr(1, Commenttext, Chr(10), vbTextCompare) + 1, Len(Commenttext))
                CL.ClearComments
            End With
        End If
    Next CL

End Sub
```